# Can't install libc6-dev-i386 package

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, dependencies

I am running Debian 9 (stretch) amd64. I tried to run a program that relies on libc6-dev-i386 to work, but I was unable to install the package using this command:

```
apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
```

I get this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libc6-dev-i386 : Depends: libc6-i386 (= 2.24-11+deb9u3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libc6-dev (= 2.24-11+deb9u3) but 2.27-6 is to be installed
                 Recommends: gcc-multilib but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to downgrade the  libc6-i386_2.27-6 version to 2.24-11+deb9u3:

```
dpkg -i --force-downgrade libc6-i386_2.24-11+deb9u3_amd64.deb.
```

but I got this:

```
 Reading database ... 274743 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libc6-i386_2.24-11+deb9u3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-i386 (2.24-11+deb9u3) over (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
Replaced by files in installed package libc6:i386 (2.27-6) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6-i386:
 libc6-i386 depends on libc6 (= 2.24-11+deb9u3); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.27-6.

dpkg: error processing package libc6-i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6-i386
```

Comment: You have a mixture of packages from Debian 9 and 10. Please [edit] your question to show the output of `apt policy`.

Comment: When I tried to edit the question with the apt polycy info, says: "You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 8 links."

Comment: If you format the output as code (with four spaces at the start of each line, or using the {} button), the links won’t count as links and you’ll be able to edit the question.